# Linearly Independent and Span

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is:
Let V = R^3. Find a set S ⊂ V such that V = Span(S) and such that S is not linearly independent. Show that your set S satisfies the claimed properties.

Let V = R^4. Find a set T ⊂ V such that T is linearly independent, but such that V 6= Span(T). Show that your set T satisfies the claimed properties.

Here are the answers, could someone please help me by explaining what these mean. Particularly the second part of the question.

Take, for example S = {s1, s2, s3, s4} where s1 = e1, s2 = e2, s3 = e3, s4 =
e1 +e2 and {e1, e2, e3} is the standard basis of R^3. We have Span(S) = R^3
as any (x, y, z) ∈ R^3 may be expressed as(x, y, z) = xe1 + ye2 + ze3.

But S is not linearly independent as
0R3 = s1 + s2 − s4.

Second Part. For example, take T = ∅. No non-trivial linear combination of vectors of T equals 0R4 . Moreover, Span(T) = {0V }, which is not the whole of R^4

Comment: If you take $\emptyset$ for the second part, why not simply take $S=V$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:In $n $dimensional space you need at least  $n $vectors to generate the whole space,in which you need to find out $n $linearly independent set to generate  $V $,which fomrs the set called as basis.In $R^3$ you need at least 3 vectors to generate  $R^3$.After constructing the basis just add any vector from $R^3$,this vector can be expressed as the liner combination of basis vectors.
Your solution of 1st part has done it exactly,Now you may find any such set $S $by choosing the basis and add any  fourth vector.

The set $T $ as your answer says, is trivialy linearly  independent and it generates nothing ,I hope you are happy.
In case of nontrivial example of $T$,You need to choose any proper subcollection of the basis,as you know basis is linearly independent and clearly can't generate the whole space.